# JBilling ActiveMQ Scheduler Exception

Tags: java, jbilling

I am trying to run jbilling 4.4.1. However I keep getting the following error;

```
Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Scheduler" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue$8.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLo
ading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1304)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClas
sLoaderBase.java:1184)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClas
sLoaderBase.java:1145)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.expireMessages(Queue.java:614
at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.access$100(Queue.java:89)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue$2.run(Queue.java:122)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.
java:33)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLo  ading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1303)
        ... 8 more
```

How can I fix this without changing the source code?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out the problem was in the database (postgreSQL)...

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation     "reseller_entityid_map" does not exist
  Position: 449
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.ja    va:2198)
```

The "reseller_entityid_map" table was missing, once created, restarted tomcat and the Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Scheduler"  error went away.

You should check the following log file:

```
jbilling-community-4.1.1/bin/logs/jbilling-stacktrace.log
```

That's where I found those errors:

```
grep -i PSQLException ./jbilling-community-4.1.1/bin/logs/jbilling-stacktrace.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root cause is some java class not found. If you can pastebin more logs preferably full startup logs i.e. tomcat/logs/catalina.out + tomcat/bin/logs/jbilling.log, it would be easier to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this fork, you will not get this problem https://github.com/WebDataConsulting/billing. This fork contains a bunch of fixes as well related to pricing and multi-tenant pricing.